# How to not print a subreport if has no data on Jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I've a master report with several `subreports`. My `JSON datasource`, may, or may not, have some content to fill an specific `subreport`. So, I would like to not show these `subreport`, not even blank pages. Which is my current situation. I can print something into the `No Data` `band`, however I'm not sure how this would help me. Is there any way of doing this ?

Comment: I moved your image into marcus answer, if you like you can make your own answer, but do not do it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the property `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"`

**In JasperReports Studio**

[image]